# Download and unzip Nifi but get warning when i run "run-nifi.bat" on WindowsServer 2017

Tags: apache-nifi

I downloaded Nifi and unzip it,
try to run but get the warning and my Nifi is not run

**command line**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.util.OSUtils (file:/C:/NiFi/lib/bootstrap/nifi-bootstrap-1.6.0.jar) to field java.lang.ProcessImpl.handle
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.util.OSUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-05-14 01:56:23,159 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NiFi\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
```

**This message shows in nifi-bootstrap LOG**

```
2018-05-14 03:06:38,655 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NiFi\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-05-14 03:06:38,655 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NiFi\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-05-14 03:06:38,671 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 4540
2018-05-14 03:06:39,436 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NiFi\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-05-14 03:06:39,436 WARN [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NiFi\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2018-05-14 03:06:39,436 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 54851 2018-05-14 03:07:54,310 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

**And this is App LOG**

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.nifi.authorization.Authorizer: Provider
org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer could not be instantiated at 
           java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581) at
           java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:390) at
           java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803) at
java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721) at
java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394) at
           org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:148) at
           org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:123) at 
           org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:771) at 
           org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157) at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71) at 
           org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException at org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAuthorizer.<init>(FileAuthorizer.java:43) at 
           java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at 
           java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at 
           java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at 
           java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488) at 
           java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779) ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException at 
           java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466) at 
           java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566) at 
           java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ... 14 common frames omitted 2018-05-14 03:07:53,294 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi 
Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server... 2018-05-14 03:07:53,294 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using java 9 probably that's the issue.

Try with JAVA 8 version

The below jira addresses similar kind of issue when we run nifi with java9
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4419